ElasticSearch 8.14 Query_string phrase search with regex
I am trying to search for a multi-word phrase using regular expressions. I would prefer to use the FVH because the unified highlighter tends to break highlighting chunks between the words within a phrase. So I would prefer to use a query_string query instead of a span_multi query.
A phrase search with query_string without regular expressions functions as expected. So
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"präsentierten Belege\"", "fields": ["text"]
    }
  }, "highlight": {"fields": {"text": {"type": "fvh"}}}
}

returns only documents where the words "präsentierten" and "Belege" occur directly next to each other. But when I try to use regular expressions, like this
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "/präsentier.*/ /Beleg.*/", "fields": ["text"]
    }
  }, "highlight": {"fields": {"text": {"type": "fvh"}}}
}

I get texts that have either a word starting with "präsentier" or with "Beleg" but not necessarily with both in the same document. If I put AND between the terms then I only get documents with both words but not necessarily in a phrase right next to each other. If I enclose the whole search query with quotation marks, like so:
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"/präsentier.*/ /Beleg.*/\"", "fields": ["text"]
    }
  }, "highlight": {"fields": {"text": {"type": "fvh"}}}
}

then I get no results even though the phrase "präsentierten Belege" exists in the documents and thus should be matched.
Is this possible without using a span query? If so, how?
FYI: The field I am trying to search is a "text" field with term_vector "with_positions_offsets" and with the "whitespace_lower" analyzer.

What about "query": "/präsentier.*Beleg/", "fields": ["text"]?

@WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the suggestion. But that also doesn't work.
